# Как совместить ASP.NET MVC и Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект изначально чистый ASP.NET MVC, хочу внедрить в него функциональность Web API. 
Добавил следующие файлы в проект:

- App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs
- Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs
- Controllers\ValuesController.cs

При запуске проекта возникают 3 ошибки:

> CS1061 'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication' and no extension method 'SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs

---

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'HostAuthenticationFilter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs

---

> CS1061    'HttpConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' and no extension method 'MapHttpAttributeRoutes' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs

Содержание App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Гугление ни к чему хорошему меня не привело(

Comment: Попробуйте вот этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554986/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-web-api-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-mvc/559543#559543

Answer (score 1):

Одних файлов недостаточно, вам нужно установить Web API нужной версии [через NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) также.

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Я все недостающие пакеты перенес в packages.config из стандартного проекта с Web API.

Comment: Нужно не переносить, а установить через NuGet. При установке прописываются настройки в XXX.config файлы и загружаются и устанавливаются соответствующие dll. (http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/data-access/details/manually-installing-references-required-by-the-web-api-service)