# Внедрение WEB API в проект MVC

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api

Всем доброго времени суток! Имеется проект MVC. Суть: информационный сайт, с авторизацией, и возможностью CRUD операций. необходимо добавить API который выступал бы посредником между данными с базы и бизнес логикой сайта. Натолкните на мысль как осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы добавить Web API в проект MVC нужно провести ряд действий.

1. Установите [библиотеки Web API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/) через менеджер пакетов Nuget.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   или используя консоль

   ```
   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi
   ```
2. В папку `AppStart` добавьте файл `WebApiConfig.cs`. В нем будет
   находится конфигурация Web API.

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
   using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

   namespace TreeTag
   {
       public static class WebApiConfig
       {
           public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
           {
               // Web API configuration and services
               // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
               config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
               config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

               // Web API routes
               config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

               config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi",
                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. После этого в файл `Global.asax.cs` добавьте строчку
   `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)` для
   регистрации Web API:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
       // Default stuff
       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

       // Manually installed WebAPI 2.2 after making an MVC project.
       GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

       // Default stuff
       FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
       BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   }
   ```

**WebAPI Help (Опционально)**

Вы можете включить также [очень удобную автоматическую генерацию документации](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) для вашего API. Для этого вам нужно установить еще один пакет через Nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`.

Консоль: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage`

**Проверка работоспособности**

Теперь можно создавать `Web API Controller` для проверки работоспособности кода.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    //public TestController() { }

    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
    //...
}
```

После этого можно билдить проект и проверять что методы работают введя запрос `http://localhost:PORT/api/Test/`